# Alternatives from NowJS

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

NowJS is a technology developed underneath the core of Node.js. It's one of promising tool to develop real-time web applications. But, there is a large number of issues using it either on Windows as like Mac platform. I decided to try on alternatives from NowJS. I realized some alternatives, but I wonder to know more viable alternatives especially if I can use it with node.js.

Alternatives:
- Pusher (It seems to be doesn't works under Node.js core);
- DNode (something similar from NowJS).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is NowJS scrapped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476943/is-nowjs-scrapped)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/) obviously. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dnode is what you want. It can be found here: https://github.com/substack/dnode.

Comment: dont link to substack, link to dnode ._.